# Как обновить данные в ListView Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-service

Есть  `Service`  и `Fragment`. Внутри фрагмента находится `ViewPager` внутри которого находится `ListView`. Сообщения от сервиса принимает `BroadcastReceiver`,  мне нужно что  бы когда в `BroadcastReceiver` поступит нужный `intent` - обновить данные в  `listView`. Каким образом это можно реализовать, вот код `fragment'a`:

**MyFragment.java**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private final String TAG = "MyFragment";
    private Context context;

    private RelativeLayout rootView;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private MyViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    private ArrayList<String> contactList;

    final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switch (intent.getAction()) {
                case MyService.BROADCAST_ACTION_UPDATE_CONTACTS:
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver receive intent");
                    viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.context = getContext();
        initData();


        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(MyService.BROADCAST_ACTION_REGISTRATION);
        filter.addAction(MyService.BROADCAST_ACTION_UPDATE_CONTACTS);
        LocalBroadcastManager bm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
        bm.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        rootView = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_contact_list_fragment, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager_companies);

        viewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);


        return rootView;
    }



    private class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        ArrayList<View> viewList;
        ContactCalingList contacts;

        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
            viewList = new ArrayList<>();
            viewList.add(0, new LinearLayout(context));
        }


        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_contacts_and_companies, container, false);
            final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_contacts);
            final ContactListAdapter listAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(context, MyApplication.getContactList());
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            container.addView(rootView);
            return rootView;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return viewList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
            collection.removeView((View) view);
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Test title";
        }
    }
}
```

Я попробовал в `ViewPage adapter'e` вынести из `instantiateItem`   метода ContactListAdapter и обновлять его в методе `refresh()` таким образом `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` ,  и это работает но у меня в каждой вкладке ViewPagera будет список и для каждого из них нужен  адаптер, т.е. не общий. как в таком случае можно решить проблему.

```
   ContactListAdapter listAdapter;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
        viewList = new ArrayList<>();
        viewList.add(0, new LinearLayout(context));
        listAdapter  = new ContactListAdapter(context, MyApplication.getContactList());

    }

    public void refresh(){
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: попробуйте `((ContactListAdapter) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview).getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();` только там NullPointerExeption вроде возможен...

Comment: @AbrogPetrovich так обновляет список только в первой странице ViewPager'a, как можно обновить во всех страницах?

Comment: а если добавить перед `getView` `((MyViewPagerAdapter) myPager.getAdapter()).getPage(myPager.getCurrentItem)`? и прописать в адаптере, чтобы `getPage` возвращал текущий `View`.